# Is there any way to get all data retrieved between two points in C# code (Linq-to-sql)

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, linq-to-sql, mocking

My cenario is the follow:
I'm working in one system developed in C# Asp.Net (a big, huge and definetly grown anyway system). And I'm trying to begin create some unit tests to start refactor (believe, it's need refactor (there some controllers with 10k, 12k lines).
The problem is that a lot of things in this system is related to database (and system is tightly coupled to database). Database context is instantiated in a lot of pieces of code, and not injected.
So, my point now is to Mock some data into local MDB file to refactor code and create unit tests that will have their own MDB (with all database structure, but with only the data that he will use).

In what I though? Something like that:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void AnyTest()
{
    var dbLogger = new DbLogger(); //this class is not created, it's just an example.
    dbLogger.Start();

     WorstWrittenMethodEver(); //this method will call any other methods insides, 
                               //a couple of then 
                               //and I really don't know the order and the
                               //complexity (much times very high), and this will probably
                               //instantiate the DataContext a lot of times and do
                               //a lot of data retrieval.

    db.StopLog();
    Console.WriteLine(db.DataRetrieved); //And in this line I will print all the tables 
   //and data retrieved between this two points.
}
```

After that, I will get that data, mock into one MDB file, and refactor the unit test above to get a really Unit Test.

Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks that it is not very easy task. And I think you should use some popular and tested library or tool. My recommendation is to use the [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/). It allows to capture all SQL queries (also includes a support of LinqToSql). It has a good UI and API to interact within your code. Actually to get all SQL queries data you can use the following method:

```
MiniProfiler.Current.GetSqlTimings();
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot, I think that, if it's not exactly what I need, it's the closer than I need. I will study the MiniProfiler and try use it. Thanks for the tip :)